Dokku Procfile "release: python manage.py migrate" results in a NodeNotFoundError "Migration XYZ dependencies reference nonexistent parent node"
When attempting to deploy to the Dokku testing environment with a Postgres database, I encounter an error while the Procfile is being utilized.
-----> Releasing aha-website-test...
-----> Checking for predeploy task
       No predeploy task found, skipping
-----> Checking for release task
       Executing release task from Procfile in ephemeral container: python manage.py migrate
=====> Start of aha-website-test release task (825335cfe) output
remote:  !     Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:  !       File "/app/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
remote:  !         execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
remote:  !         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^
remote:  !       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.13/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
remote:  !         utility.execute()
remote:  !         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^
remote:  !       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.13/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 436, in execute
remote:  !         self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
remote:  !         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^
remote:  !       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.13/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 413, in run_from_argv
remote:  !         self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
remote:  !         ~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
remote:  !       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.13/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 459, in execute
remote:  !         output = self.handle(*args, **options)
remote:  !       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.13/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 107, in wrapper
remote:  !         res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
remote:  !       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.13/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 118, in handle
remote:  !         executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
remote:  !       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.13/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
remote:  !         self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
remote:  !                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
remote:  !       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.13/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 58, in __init__
remote:  !         self.build_graph()
remote:  !         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^
remote:  !       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.13/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 276, in build_graph
remote:  !         self.graph.validate_consistency()
remote:  !         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^
remote:  !       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.13/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 198, in validate_consistency
remote:  !         [n.raise_error() for n in self.node_map.values() if isinstance(n, DummyNode)]
remote:  !          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^
remote:  !       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.13/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 60, in raise_error
remote:  !         raise NodeNotFoundError(self.error_message, self.key, origin=self.origin)
remote:  !     django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration generic.0001_initial dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('wagtailcore', '0092_query_searchpromotion_querydailyhits')

The Procfile
release: python manage.py migrate

I cannot reproduce this locally. I also removed the db and every migration, and still no error, migrations where applied without any errors.
Wagtail version: 6.2.2
Django version: 5.1.2
psycopg version: 3.2.3

Somewhere in your project - probably search/views.py - you have imported the models from wagtail.contrib.search_promotions.models without adding wagtail.contrib.search_promotions to INSTALLED_APPS. This caused Django to think these models were part of the core wagtail app, and created a stray migration for them inside your local installation's Wagtail package. The migrations in your generic app now have a dependency on this stray migration which only exists in your local installation, causing an error when they are run elsewhere.
To fix this, first add wagtail.contrib.search_promotions to your project's INSTALLED_APPS. Then, edit the file generic/migrations/0001_initial.py and change the line
("wagtailcore", "0092_query_searchpromotion_querydailyhits"),

to
('wagtailcore', '0091_remove_revision_submitted_for_moderation'),

You may need to search your other migrations for other occurrences of this line, and change those too.
With this change in place, the migrations should then complete correctly.

Thanks for your time and effort!!! I actually dont use the search app in my project but it is still there. After removing it and change all the other migrations with the line you've added i get this error: django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: NewQueryDailyHits has no field named 'query'. Its also from the search but i removed that app and all its usage in the wagtail application.
